# send two argument by postback

Tags: c#, javascript

I use the `__dopostback` function in javascript page to send some information to the `RaisepostbackEvent()` method in my c# page.

`RaisepostbackEvent()` method accepts just one string argument, but I want to send two string arguments.

Comment: Accept some of your questions

Comment: Concatenate the 2 strings(with a delimiter) and send them as one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could join the two strings using a separator character and split them on the client.

on the server:

```
result = string1 + "|" + string2;
```

on the client:

```
   var strings = result.split("|"); 
   if (strings.length == 2) 
   {
     var string1 = strings[0];      
     var string2 = strings[1];
   }
```